# Attaching an onsubit function to a form with arguments

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a function I want to attach to all forms passing the form itself as an argument. When I submit the form, I see that the function gets called, but the argument is either null or some other element in the DOM.

This method is already called within a class, so `this` is probably the wrong thing to pass, but `forms[i]` did not work either. What do I pass in place of the `?`, or is there a better way?

```
var forms=this.content.getElementsByTagName('form');
for(var i=0;i<forms.length;++i){
    // TODO: handle if there is already an onsubmit() function
    forms[i].onsubmit=function(){SubmitForm(?);}
}
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue

Comment: @undefined, in this particular case since onsubmit callback is usually has its context set to the form couldn't OP just do `SubmitForm(this);`, instead of dealing with closures

Comment: @PatrickEvans—"context"? You mean the listener's *this* will be set to the element. Functions have an execution context, of which *this* is but one parameter.

Comment: @RobG, yes that is what I mean the execution context. I was just addressing the issue of passing the form element, as that is all OP mentions, they do not mention any other arguments needing passed besides in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this`, since it's inside a loop, it refers to the current form.

```
forms[i].addEventListener("submit", function() {
    SubmitForm(this);
});
```